# how to get date different in postgres using date_part option

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, recursive-query, postgresql-9.5

How to get date time difference in PostgreSQL

I am using below syntax

```
select id, A_column,B_column, 
      (SELECT count(*) AS count_days_no_weekend 
       FROM generate_series(B_column ::timestamp , A_column ::timestamp, interval  '1 day') the_day 
       WHERE  extract('ISODOW' FROM the_day) < 5) * 24 + DATE_PART('hour', B_column::timestamp-A_column ::timestamp ) as hrs 
FROM table req where id='123';
```

If A_column=2020-05-20 00:00:00 and B_column=2020-05-15 00:00:00 I want to get 72(in hours).

Is there any possibility to skip weekends(Saturday and Sunday) in first one, it means to get the result as 72 hours(exclude weekend hours)

i am getting 0

But i need to get 72 hours

And if If A_column=2020-08-15 12:00:00 and B_column=2020-08-15 00:00:00 I want to get 12(in hours).

Comment: A calendar table would be the recommended approach.

Comment: Your second example, 08/15/2020, is a Saturday.  Why would it return 12 instead of 0?

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a lateral join and `generate_series()` to enumerate each and every hour between the two timestamps, while filtering out week-ends:

```
select t.a_column, t.b_column, h.count_hours_no_weekend 
from mytable t
cross join lateral (
    select count(*) count_hours_no_weekend 
    from generate_series(t.b_column::timestamp, t.a_column::timestamp, interval '1 hour') s(col)
    where extract('isodow' from s.col) < 5
) h
where id = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

I would attack this by calculating the weekend hours to let the database deal with daylight savings time.  I would then subtract the intervening weekend hours from the difference between the two date values.

```
with weekend_days as (
  select *, date_part('isodow', ddate) as dow
    from table1
         cross join lateral 
           generate_series(
             date_trunc('day', b_column),
             date_trunc('day', a_column),
             interval '1 day') as gs(ddate)
   where date_part('isodow', ddate) in (6, 7)
), weekend_time as (
  select id, 
         sum( 
           least(ddate + interval '1 day', a_column) -
           greatest(ddate, b_column)
         ) as we_ival
    from weekend_days
   group by id
)
select t.id, 
       a_column - b_column as raw_difference,
       coalesce(we_ival, interval '0') as adjustment,
       a_column - b_column - 
         coalesce(we_ival, interval '0') as adj_difference
  from weekend_time w
       left join table1 t on t.id = w.id;
```

[Working fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/csp4mtpnog5KTQuw74RWUb/0)